# how to define route for single component in angular 2 so that each route is linked to different function of that component

Tags: angular2-routing

Actually what i am trying to do is to create a component that can be used to perform CRUD operations but i am unable to add different routes for different function i.e. even when i perform add operation it shows path like http://localhost:3000/#/product and when it shows list of all products or when i want to edit and product it shows same path. so how to define path so that each path corresponds to different function of the same component. Please some help as i am new to this technology.

Comment: So you want to manually set the route name without changing routes? I'm not sure this is possible

Comment: is there any way to define route automatically in angular 2?